# why using the assignment operator instead of equal to operator works in the following situation?

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, selection

You should have a condition which should evaluate to true or false in order for an `if` statement to work. I don't understand how `p=fopen("test.txt", "r")` part of the following code evaluates to true or false since it only contains an assignment operator `=` and not a `==` operator.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  FILE *p;
  if(p=fopen("test.txt","r"))
  {
      printf("yes\n");
  }
  else
    printf("no\n");
  return 0;
```

Comment: You need to check if p is null or not, so fopen() was sucessfull or not!

Comment: @Gonçalo But that's happening implicitly here, and the question is why.

Comment: @Rup yes tha's true

Comment: @Rup So imagine that you has a code that depends from your file in this case `p` and your are using the option `r` to read it, but imagine that your file doesnt exists, you will have a big problem on your program, so you need to check if `fopen() `
went well. In another case, that you use somethin to create the file and read it! It will have no problem, because you will create it! But in this case you have a problem if file does not exist

Comment: @Gonçalo Yes, and OP's code is already doing that: it will `printf("yes\n");` if `p` is not null and `printf("no\n");` if it is null. The question is why does `if(p=fopen("test.txt","r"))` implicitly test whether `p` is null or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use assignment, then `p` will contain uninitialized garbage. In general, it is considered bad practice to use the assignment operator inside conditions (most compilers will warn against it), because it's dangerous and hard to read. But it is perfectly valid, because the `=` operator has a result like most operators, in this case the value of `p`.

So the code in your example is a sloppier, worse way of writing

```
p=fopen("test.txt","r")
if(p)
```

which in turn is a sloppier version of

```
if(p != NULL)
```

Comment: yep this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 5):

From the `C11` spec, chapter 6.5.16,

> " An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment [....]"

So basically, you code is same as

```
p=fopen("test.txt","r");
if(p) {  // or, if (p != NULL) for ease of understanding
 // do something

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

From the C Standard )6.8.4.1 The if statement)

> 2 **In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression
> compares unequal to 0.** In the else form, the second substatement is
> executed if the expression compares equal to 0. If the first
> substatement is reached via a label, the second substatement is not
> executed.

and (6.5.16 Assignment operators)

> 3 An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by
> the left operand. **An assignment expression has the value of the left
> operand after the assignment**,111) but is not an lvalue

So the value of the expression

```
p=fopen("test.txt","r")
```

is a pointer that in case of a successful call of the function `fopen` is not equal to 0.